# "does not name a type" error when appending to vector

Tags: c++, scope

```
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h" // EDIT: added
Node node1(true,11);
Node node2(true,04);
std::vector<Node> room1;
room1.push_back(node1);
```

I just want to add node1 to the vector of nodes named room1.To me it looks exactly how the tutorials instruct, however I am getting an error "room1 does not name a type."

---

**Edit:** Header to node has been included.  All Node does is a take in (bool,int) and stores it.  *(The program is several hundred lines long just trying to keep the content relevant.)*

Comment: where do you define `Node` ?

Comment: Did you simply miss to `#include "Node.h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error about `room1` not naming a type comes from your code not being inside a function or object method.  You can put definitions in the outer scope of your file, but not lines of arbitrary code to execute.  Code needs a context to run in.

```
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"

int main() {
    Node node1(true,11);
    Node node2(true,04);
    std::vector<Node> room1;
    room1.push_back(node1);
}
```

Note that not returning a result here from main is a very specific allowance made for `main()`, by the C++ specification:

[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Other functions you write should have a return statement if they have a return type.

Answer (score 1):

This is forbidden by the grammar of `C++` as the only things allowed in namespace scope are [declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). These could be class, function or nested namespace declarations. Since `room1.push_back(node1);` doesn't fall in this category, your program is ill-formed. You probably want to put it in a function. The simplest of examples would be putting it in `main`:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h" // EDIT: added
Node node1(true,11);
Node node2(true,04);
std::vector<Node> room1;

int main()
{
room1.push_back(node1);
return 0;
}
```

You likely want `room1`, `node1` and `node2` moved to `main` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the header for `Node` or, more generally, `Node` is not a visible type in the current translation unit.